# Can I enlarge the '.container' in Bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, web

I have a page in Bootstrap but I want the `.container` to be wider. Can I change the `width` of this `.container`?

Comment: Do you try to change anything in the custom.css

Comment: yup, you can do the changes in required changes in your custom css. Dont touch Bootstrap.css

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several possibilities:

**custom css**

As it has already been suggested, you can just overwrite the default in your own css. Keep in mind, that you'll probably have to use media queries define several of these for different screen sizes

**customizing bootstrap**

On [bootstrap's own customization page](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/) you can change practically any definition and generate a customized version of bootstrap. Look for the section called *Container sizes*

**fluid container**

If you just want a container that spans the entire width of your screen, use `.container-fluid` instead of `.container`

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  ...
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can easily override the default presentation of Bootstrap, just include your own CSS file, and do the following:

```
.container {
    /* Write your custom width here! */ 
}
```